# Redux mapStatmentToProps returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

everyone.

Have been having an issue for several days that I can't seem to solve. 
In my Redux Application, I'll have three different components `PostComponent` `PostDetails` `Posts` In `PostComponent` a post(the UI that builds a single post) is being built. Part of this UI I need to have a "number of comments" (Comments: 2 etc.) My reducer is built up in a way that returns a grouped object of comments under the key of every main post.

This state of my Redux store is then being `mapStateToProps`within `PostComponent` however currently I'm receiving `undefined`at the route `/` its `comments` that returns it and when I'm on a Detailed view `/:category/:postId` my `ownProps.postId` is returning `undefined`

Would really appreciate if anyone has any idea why this is happening!

**Repo:** https://github.com/petterostergren/readable_udacity

---

Comments reducer `state = {}`

```
case COMMENTS_GET_COMMENTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        comments: _.groupBy(action.payload, 'parentId'),
      }
```

Posts (`/`)

```
class Posts extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { getPosts } = this.props
    getPosts()
  }

  renderPosts() {
    const { posts } = this.props
    return _.map(posts, post => {
      return (
        <div>
          <PostComponent
            key={post.id}
            postId={post.id}
            title={post.title}
            body={false}
            readirect
            author={post.author}
            voteScore={post.voteScore}
            category={post.category}
            timestamp={post.timestamp}
          />
        </div>
      )
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderPosts()}</div>
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    posts: _.filter(state.posts, ['deleted', false]),
  }),
  {
    getPosts,
  }
)(Posts)
```

PostDetailes (`/:category/:postID`)

```
class PostDetails extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { getPosts, getComments, match } = this.props
    getPost(match.params.postId)
    getComments(match.params.postId)
  }

  renderComments() {
    const { comments, posts, match } = this.props
    return _.map(comments, comment => {
      return (
        <PostComponent
          key={comment.id}
          postId={comment.id}
          isPost={false}
          title=""
          body={comment.body}
          readirect={false}
          author={comment.author}
          voteScore={comment.voteScore}
          category=""
          timestamp={comment.timestamp}
        />
      )
    })
  }

  renderPosts() {
    const { posts } = this.props
    return (
      <PostComponent
        key={posts.id}
        postId={posts.id}
        title={posts.title}
        body={posts.body}
        readirect={false}
        author={posts.author}
        voteScore={posts.voteScore}
        category={posts.category}
        timestamp={posts.timestamp}
      />
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderPosts()} <hr /> {this.renderComments()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  console.log("PostDetails, mapStateToProps ownProps ")
  console.log(ownProps)
  return {
    comments: state.comments[ownProps.match.params.postId],
    posts: _.filter(state.posts, ['deleted', false]),
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPost, getComments })(PostDetails)
```

PostComponent ( The one being injected )

```
class PostComponent extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const { postId } = this.props
    getComments(postId)
  }

  renderNumberOfCommets(postId) {
    const { comments } = this.props
    return _.map(comments, comment => {
      {
        JSON.stringify(comments)
      }
    })
  }

  renderPost() {
    const {
      postId,
      title,
      voteScore,
      author,
      category,
      timestamp,
      body,
      readirect,
      pushVotePost,
      comments,
    } = this.props
    const time = timeConverter(timestamp)
    console.log('comments')
    console.log(comments)
    return (
      <div key={postId}>
        <div className="">
          <ul className="">
            <li>
              <p>
                <span
                  className="fa fa-angle-up voteArrow"
                  onClick={() => pushVotePost('upVote', postId)}
                />
              </p>
            </li>
            <li className="votes">{voteScore}</li>
            <li>
              <span
                className="fa fa-angle-down voteArrow"
                onClick={() => pushVotePost('downVote', postId)}
              />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="">
          <Link to={`${category}`}>
            <span className="">{category}</span>
          </Link>
          {readirect ? (
            <Link to={`${category}/${postId}`}>
              <h3 className="">{title}</h3>
              <p>{body ? `${body}` : ''}</p>
              <p>Comments: {comments}</p>
              <footer className="">
                Writte by {author}, {time}
              </footer>
            </Link>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <h3 className="">{title}</h3>
              <p>{body ? `${body}` : ''}</p>
              <footer className="">
                Writte by {author}, {time}
                {/* TODO: Comments should go here in a numbered format. */}
                <p>Comments: {this.renderNumberOfCommets(postId)}</p>
              </footer>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderPost()}</div>
  }
}

PostComponent.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string,
  voteScore: PropTypes.number,
  title: PropTypes.string,
  author: PropTypes.string,
  category: PropTypes.string,
  timestamp: PropTypes.number,
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  console.log('PostComponent, mapStateToProps ownProps')
  console.log(ownProps)
  return {
    comments: state.comments.comments,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { pushVotePost, getComments })(
  PostComponent
)
```

Comment: Are you combining the reducers? also, which line is returning undefined?

Comment: Is `state.comments` populated with the data you expect in `mapStateToProps()`?

Comment: @MatthewBarbara Hi, yes im combining my reducers. Inside of `PostComponent` when I currently `JSON.stringify(comments)` (just for testing)

Comment: @skypecakes When im on `/:category/:postId` its returing what I excpect. But on `/` its returing undefinded...

Comment: My question wasn't about what mapStateToProps() is returning, it's, what is the content of `state`? My hope was that the question would prompt you to go to the code that's meant to populate `state.comments` and troubleshoot there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi everyone I ended up changing a few things to get it to work

Built ut my reducer as following:

```
import { COMMENTS_GET_COMMENTS } from '../actions/actionConstants'

const comments = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case COMMENTS_GET_COMMENTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.meta]: action.payload,
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default comments
```

and then call it within my component as

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    comments: state.comments[ownProps.postId]
      ? state.comments[ownProps.postId]
      : [],
  }
}
```

this gave me the possibility to then use it as `{this.props.comments.length}` within my UI